# asp.net mvc 4 display modes and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've been playing around with ASP.net MVC 4's new Display Mode functionality where you can append .Mobile to a display page (Index.Mobile.cshtml) and it will render the mobile version for mobile devices.  Is it possible to have different controllers for the different user agents?  Something like HomeController.Mobile.cs?  I've tried this, but it's not working.  Compiler wants HomeController.cs and HomeController.Mobile.cs to be partials.

I know I can create a Mobile area and redirect all mobile traffic to that area so mobile devices will have their own controllers.  But, I would prefer to have something like HomeController.Mobile.cs so it makes for a cleaner codebase.  Otherwise, using ASP.net 4's Display Modes the mobile version and the web version of a page will have the same controller logic which is not always needed.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File names don't mean anything for classes, so I'm not sure what are you envisioning with the "HomeController.Mobile.cs" idea. You can't have two HomeController classes by the same name so it's either separate controllers/areas/apps or a shared one, as you noted.

If you go with the default convention and have the same controller, you can fork off your logic based on device type:

```
if (HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice)
{
    //mobile specific logic
}
```

If you find that many controllers/actions have different logic depending on the device type then I'd argue that **you have separate applications** and it *does* make sense to use an area or even a separate web application if needed, IMHO. I'd try to decide what path I went based on this.

Edit to address the comments:

I understand what you want; I had to do something similar when I tried to make a jQuery Mobile version of my blog. Basically, there are 3 options as I see it:

1. Controllers with a single set of logic that retrieves all data for all views. Each view simply uses what it needs.
2. Controllers with an "if(isMobile)" that does certain logic and returns a mobile view in the case of mobile devices, and does different logic and returns the default view in others.
3. A completely separate area or application explicitly for mobile (eg. mobile.yourapp.com)

Sounds like you don't want #2 or #3, so have you considered #1? The bottleneck in mobile devices is its resources and the network, so I wouldn't be too concerned if your server had to do "extra" work to get some set of data that the mobile view never rendered.

Comment: mobile devices are different than web pages.  Most notably real estate size of the screen.  I'm thinking that for any given request, if a web page, then I can provide more content to fill up the screen real estate then what I can do for a mobile device.  MVC 4 is providing some great functionality for switching views based on user agent.  I can have different views based on differed interfaces, however, I'm stuck with the same controller for gathering different sets of data for the different views.  I dont want "if(isMobileDevice)" in controller.  Any other options?

Comment: sorry, ran out of character in first comment...  Anyways, for a given request I want to supply different data (i.e. different interfaces) based on the user agent.  How can I effectively do that in the controller?

Comment: If you require different data for different devices, then I would argue they should not share the same View. The best way to do this is with separate controllers in a different Area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts.  This has helped alot.  I had not thought of option #1.  I think that may be the best way to go.  Thanks